# Unity gameobject not destroying

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm building some somtware that displays a text every time you load a certain screen. I'm trying to delete all previous text so that I can load new text every time I load the view. But for some reason I can't seem to destroy the gameobjects holding the text, and ends up duplicating the text I already had.

```
private void SetPages(List<string> strings)
{
    Clear();
    foreach (string page in strings)
        AddPage(page);
}

private void AddPage(string text)
{
    Text page = instantiator.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<Text>(textPrefab);
    page.GetComponent<Text>().text = text;
    page.transform.SetParent(root, false);
    texts.Add(page);
}

private void Clear()
{
    if(texts != null)
    {
        foreach (Text text in texts)
        {
            oldTexts.Add(text);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < oldTexts.Count; i++)
        {
            Destroy(oldTexts[i].gameObject);
        }
        oldTexts.Clear();
        texts.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need oldTexts. just do

```
foreach (Text text in texts)
{
    Destroy(text.gameObject);
}
```

also, this part:

> ```
> page.GetComponent<Text>().text = text;
> ```

can be simplified to

```
page.text = text;
```

since you're already getting the `Text` component from instantiation.